# How to reference an array with a function prior to bash4.3

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, bash-functions, bash-array

**If we:**

1. Define an array; and then..
2. Define a function; and want to..
3. Call that array from inside the function..

We can. Like so:

---

**Input:**

```
myArray=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5')

myFunction () 
{ 
local -n myList="$1";
echo "${myList[@]}";
}

myFunction myArray
```

---

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

---

So, `${myArray[@]}` becomes `${myList[@]}`, within the scope of `myFunction`.

But this method only works as of `bash` version 4.3.x.

How did (and how can) we do this with older versions?

Answer (score 3):

In older bashes, you need "variable indirection" (4th paragraph of [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)),
which is really ugly for arrays:

```
myArray=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5')
myFunction() {
    local arr="${1}[@]"         # array expansion *as a string*
    local values=( "${!arr}" )  # actual array expansion
    echo "${values[@]}"
}
myFunction myArray
```

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Note that this gives you a **copy** of the array. Any modifications you make in the function will **not** alter `myArray` in the outer scope:

```
myFunc2_old () {
    local arr="${1}[@]"
    local values=( "${!arr}" )  # here's the copy
    values[0]=foo
    declare -p values
}
myFunc2_old myArray; declare -p myArray
```

```
declare -a values=([0]="foo" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")
declare -a myArray=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")
```

As opposed to namerefs

```
myFunc2_ref () {
    local -n arr=$1
    arr[0]=foo
    declare -p arr
}
myFunc2_ref myArray; declare -p myArray
```

```
declare -n arr="myArray"
declare -a myArray=([0]="foo" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5")
```

Comment: Thanks, let me just wrap my mind around that for a minute..  Is it both `local arr="${1}[@]"` AND `local values=( "${!arr}" )`? Or just one or the other?

Comment: You need both. The first statement sets `arr="myArray[@]"` -- that's just a string. Then `${!arr}` becomes `${myArray[@]}` with indirect expansion. Then with the parentheses and double quotes, you get the elements of the array, forming the copy.

Comment: This has the same issue when the original array also has the name `arr`. It creates a cyclic name resolution. I recommend to use something more complicated name like `__array__`. Also to mutate the original array, one can use `eval` command

Comment: I've come to use the function name as the nameref variable prefix: `__myFunc2_ref__arr` -- very ugly but unique.